# Convexity of a certain set

Tags: convex-analysis

Would someone please help me?
I know that the set
$$\{(x,y)\mid \cos(x+y)\geq \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\}$$ 
is convex, but I am seeking for a simple proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your set $$S=\{(x,y)\mid \cos(x+y)\geq \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\}$$ is not convex. $P_1=(0,0)\in S$ and $P_2=(2 \pi,0)\in S$ however $\frac{P_1+P_2}{2}\notin S$

Comment: please add the restriction $-\frac{\pi}{4}\leq x+y \leq \frac{\pi}{4} $